# Error Code=3 on start

Tags: game-dev-story

I try to play 'Game Dev Story' on my Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.1.1.
But when I want so start the App, I get 'Error Code=3'.
The Demo runs perfect, but not the current version 1.0.7

Comment: Have you tried re-downloading/installing? Have you uninstalled the demo version yet? Have you tried "clearing data" on the Google Play store?

Comment: It should be fixed by now.

Comment: Gotta say, this is kind of ironic.

Answer (score 0):

> http://pl.appbrain.com/app/game-dev-story/net.kairosoft.android.gamedev3en

Looks like a Bug on Android 4.1 Jelly Bean, only Galaxy Nexus or Nexus7 got this problems

Comment: That link doesn't really help much; I'm not sure where it says this is bug in Android.

Comment: no, the bug is not in Android, it is in the game. i've to wait untill it is fixed and updated to the marked